# Une nuance entre « forcément » et « devoir »

Tags: sens

> Mon père y a **forcément** déployé ses défenses et ces accès **doivent** être farouchement gardés.

Quand « devoir » signifie une certitude, est-ce que c’est interchangeable avec « forcément » ?

> Mon père y a **dû** déployer ses défenses et ces accès sont **forcément** farouchement gardés.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Forcément*" est bien plus fort que "*devoir*".

"*Il a dû*" veux dire "*probablement, j'imagine*". C'est une forte probabilité, mais c'est pas 100%.

"*Forcément*" indique un probabilité certaine. Il n'y a pas moyen qu'il en soit autrement.

> Si tu veux prendre l'avion, il te faut **forcément** un passeport ! Tu peux pas faire autrement !
>
> Il ne m'a pas donné son cadeau, il **a dû** oublier. Je lui rappellerai la prochaine fois que je le vois.